# Как вызвать через скрипт нужное событие onclick

Tags: javascript

Есть блок div (из чата от wowander social cms)

```
    <div class="messages-recipients-list mobileopenlist" id="messages-group-47" onclick="Wo_GetGroupMessages(47,'Чат №1');">содержимое блока</div>
```

Нужно его вызвать отдельным javascript делаю так

`document.getElementById("messages-group-47").onclick("Wo_GetGroupMessages(47,'Чат №1')");`

по  разному пробовал, никак не работает, div не вызывается.

Большая просьба мне помочь в этой непонятной мне ситуации

вот div этот при клике по названию чата открывается окно чата

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFbAT.png

вот так вызывается

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PhqZ.png

а мне необходимо прописать условие вызова javscript через GET запрос (php)
Запрос php я сам напишу там всего если получен ID чата то echo '<скрипт>вызов окна чата  /скрипт>';

а вот как сам вызов по onclick сделать проблема, не знаю

Comment: `Wo_GetGroupMessages` - это что, где оно находится?

Comment: Вставьте в редакторе работающий код, оставив только код, содержащий суть вопроса

Comment: "div не вызывается" - какой смысл Вы вкладываете в словосочетание "вызвать div"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Wo_GetGroupMessages(key, title) {
  $(<okno chata>).load("/load_chat.php", { key: key });
}
```